# issue with INNER JOIN getting information from one table to the other

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the correct image from gifts table using gift_id from users_gifts were I search the to_user_id and get the gift_id and then match it with gifts table id then send it over to display the correct image but am having some trouble here my tables and code, if anyone can help that be great thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE `gifts` (
  `gift_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `gift_price` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gift_pro` int(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE `users_gifts` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `from_user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `gift_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;



public function get_my_gifts($user_id) {
        global $db;
        $my_gifts = [];
        $get_my_gifts = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT gifts.image FROM users_gifts INNER JOIN gifts ON `users_gifts`.gift_id = `gifts`.gift_id WHERE users_gifts.to_user_id = %s", secure($user_id, 'int') )) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");

        if($get_my_gifts->num_rows > 0) {
            while($my_gift = $get_my_gifts->fetch_assoc()) {
                $my_gifts[] = $my_gift;
            }
        }
        return $my_gifts;

}
```

Comment: Just for debugging purposes try this query: `SELECT image FROM gifts, users_gifts WHERE users_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id AND to_user_id='XXX'`  If that works then you know you have a syntax error somewhere in your query code. Once you workout the problem be sure to sanitize the data before plopping into the query.

Comment: I did as you says
$get_my_gifts = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT image FROM gifts, users_gifts WHERE users_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id AND to_user_id = %s", secure($user_id, 'int') )) or _error("SQL_ERROR_THROWEN");

how ever it still seams like there is a issue as it still dont display any images mmm

Comment: Do you have access to phpmaydmin? Try running the query there, to see if it's the query or your php code

Comment: For debugging purposes, try running the query like this: `"SELECT image FROM gifts, users_gifts WHERE users_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id AND to_user_id = '$user_id'"`

Comment: ok ran the code in phpadmin and its a blank image

SELECT image FROM gifts, users_gifts WHERE users_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id AND to_user_id = 10;

there is five entrys with user_id = 10 but for some reason it dont see them

Comment: here a screen shot of the tables in question
https://i.ibb.co/Df00fZq/image-2021-10-14-195005.png

Comment: My guess is you don't want an INNER JOIN here but the fact that the gift id shows as 0 and is duplicated could also be an indication that there's problem with your data.

Comment: the duplicated ID is correct as that is basicly image 0, it should list all the same images for the correct user its a image gift system so a person gifts them the same image and it display on profile of that user.

Comment: I agree with @Sherif . I think your data is not correctly entered in your database nor do you need an inner join. Can you show us all the rows for both tables?

Comment: ok ill check it out thanks for the advice peeps :)